# How do you remove the last value in an array if it doesn't match the first value in the next array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object, calendar

I might not be asking the right question here.

I'm retrieving bookings that have the first night and last night date and I'm trying to display on a calendar which dates are not available.

The date comes in as: `firstNight: "2022-02-05"` and currently, it needs to go out as `Sat Feb 05 2022`

In order to get a list of booked dates, I am doing the following:

```
const bookedDates = bedsData?.map(({ firstNight, lastNight }) => {
    const newArrivalDate = new Date(firstNight + "T00:00")
    const newDepartureDate = new Date(lastNight + "T24:00")

    var getDaysArray = function (start, end) {
      for (
        var arr = [], dt = new Date(start);
        dt <= end;
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)
      ) {
        arr.push(new Date(dt).toDateString())
      }
      return arr
    }
    var daylist = getDaysArray(newArrivalDate, newDepartureDate)

    daylist?.map((v) => v)

    return daylist.join(", ")
  })
```

This returns

```
0: undefined
1: "Sat Feb 05 2022, Sun Feb 06 2022, Mon Feb 07 2022, Tue Feb 08 2022, Wed Feb 09 2022, Thu Feb 10 2022, Fri Feb 11 2022, Sat Feb 12 2022"
2: undefined
3: "Sat Feb 12 2022, Sun Feb 13 2022, Mon Feb 14 2022, Tue Feb 15 2022, Wed Feb 16 2022, Thu Feb 17 2022, Fri Feb 18 2022, Sat Feb 19 2022"
4: "Sat Feb 19 2022, Sun Feb 20 2022, Mon Feb 21 2022, Tue Feb 22 2022, Wed Feb 23 2022, Thu Feb 24 2022, Fri Feb 25 2022, Sat Feb 26 2022"
5: undefined
6: undefined
7: "Sat Feb 26 2022, Sun Feb 27 2022, Mon Feb 28 2022, Tue Mar 01 2022, Wed Mar 02 2022, Thu Mar 03 2022, Fri Mar 04 2022, Sat Mar 05 2022"
8: "Sat Mar 05 2022, Sun Mar 06 2022, Mon Mar 07 2022, Tue Mar 08 2022, Wed Mar 09 2022, Thu Mar 10 2022, Fri Mar 11 2022, Sat Mar 12 2022"
9: undefined
10: undefined
11: "Fri Mar 25 2022, Sat Mar 26 2022, Sun Mar 27 2022, Mon Mar 28 2022, Tue Mar 29 2022"
```

To show which dates are booked I'm am using

```
if (bookedDates.join().includes(calDates)) {
    style.textDecoration = "line-through"
    style.color = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)"
}
```

[image: calendar showing bookedDates / available dates]

The issue I'm facing is with dates that don't have a check out and check in on the same day. The "last day" and the "first day" of the next booking are still being included in the list of "bookedDates". However, they need to be "available" to check out or check in still.

I hope that makes sense... pretty lost with this one!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understud, but isn't it just a confusion with start and end limits of your for loop ?
Did you try initializing with

```
if (firstNight!==lastNight) {   
   const newArrivalDate = new Date(firstNight + "T24:00")
   const newDepartureDate = new Date(lastNight + "T00:00")
} else {
   const newArrivalDate = new Date(firstNight + "T00:00")
   const newDepartureDate = new Date(lastNight + "T00:00")
}
```

Comment: The `firstNight` and `lastNight` will never be the same within each booking being mapped over if that makes sense? I think I would need to somehow check if the `lastNight` is the same as the `firstNight` in the following booking before changing the start and end limits of the for loop wouldn't I?

Comment: I corrected my post probably while you were replying, but anyway, @RobG's answer seems to be more accurate... If you want to adapt it to a list that contain undefined values you'll just have to remove the undefined values with a code like : bookings=bookings.filter(booking => booking!==undefined)

Comment: ah ok, I think @RobG's answer isn't quite there yet as I can't get it to work for the use case where someone needs to check out on the same date as someone checks in (firstNight). Running a conditional to adjust the first and last date seems logical, I just don't know how to do it across different keys. ie. Check the last value of Key 3, against the first value of Key 4.

Comment: I don't understand, since one night cannot be occupied by two persons who books, why his code isn't accurate ?
The problems seems coming from the fact your list has duplicate entries, then you should avoid duplicate entries...
One way to do this is to push all the dates in a list, then push only if the date is not already in the list. 
if (list.indexOf(date)===-1) {
    list.push(date);
}
this example should be adapted in order to work in your context, but the idea is here.
But I think @RobG's answer is accurate since you have to leave the last day "available" when one person clicks.

Comment: One way to substract one day from lastNight if you take in consideration the day of departure rather than the real last night is to replace in the while condition <= by <

Comment: The duplicate entries are technically correct, you could have someone check-out on Feb 10, and someone check-in on Feb 10. If you change <= to < that works for one end of the booking but not the other. If someone checks-out on Feb 10, and you used <, it would now strike out up to Feb 9 and allow Feb 10 to be "available" to select as a check-in day, great! However, if there is a future booking from Feb 17 - 21, Feb 17 will also be struck out on the calendar. This means if someone wanted to book from Feb 10 and check-out on the 17th, they couldn't select Feb 17 as their check-out day. 

Answer (score 0):

I presume that in `new Date(lastNight + "T24:00")` that *lastNight* is in the format YYYY-MM-DD. Because there is no offset, the string will be parsed as local and the date will be set to 00:00 on the following day, i.e. 2022-02-06T24:00 will create a date with an identical time value to 2022-02-07T00:00.

It seems your souce data is booked nights, which you want to do use to disable dates that can't be selected as checkout days. So wherever there is an un–booked night, the following day can be selected as a checkout day even if it's booked.

So when making the array of dates to disable, check for gaps and remove the first booked date. You'll have to deal with this in the UI to indicate that the date can't be booked for checkin.

Another method would be to create the booked nights array, then wherever there's a gap delete the following night as gaps must always be two dates. The first is available for check in only, the last for checkout only.

E.g.

```js
// Parse YYYY-MM-DD as local, not UTC
function parseLocal(s) {
  let [y,m,d] = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(y, m-1, d);
}
// Format as YYYY-MM-DD
function format(date = new Date()) {
  return date.toLocaleDateString('en-CA'); // YYYY-MM-DD
}
// Add day to date (modifies date)
function addDay(date = new Date()) {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  return date;
}

let bookings = [
 {id: 0,
  firstNight: '2022-02-05',
  lastNight: '2022-02-09'
 },
 {id: 1,
  firstNight: '2022-02-10', // Contiguous booking, no gap
  lastNight: '2022-02-15'
 },
  {id: 2,
  firstNight: '2022-02-17', // Gap, 17th available for check out
  lastNight: '2022-02-20'
 },
  {id: 3,
  firstNight: '2022-02-21', // No gap, not avilable for checkout
  lastNight: '2022-02-21'
 },
  {id: 4,
  firstNight: '2022-02-22', // No gap, not avilable for checkout
  lastNight: '2022-02-22'
 },
  {id: 4,
  firstNight: '2022-02-24', // Gap, avilable for checkout
  lastNight: '2022-02-24'
 },
  {id: 4,
  firstNight: '2022-02-25', // No gap, not avilable for checkout
  lastNight: '2022-02-25'
 }
]

let bookedDates = bookings.map(
  ({firstNight, lastNight}) => [parseLocal(firstNight), parseLocal(lastNight)]
  ).reduce((dates, [firstNight, lastNight], i, mapDates) => {
    // If lastNight of previous booking is not prevNight,
    // don't add firstNight to array
    let prevBookedNight = i? mapDates[i-1][1] : null;
    if (i && format(addDay(prevBookedNight)) != format(firstNight)) {
      addDay(firstNight);
    }

  while (firstNight <= lastNight) {
    dates.push(format(firstNight));
    firstNight.setDate(firstNight.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return dates;
},[]);

console.log('Not available for check in or out:\n' + bookedDates.join('\n'));
```

Comment: I had the same thought regarding the logical way to think about it (leave it as the last night or modify it to be the "check out" day.

The date comes in as: `firstNight: "2022-02-05"` and currently, it needs to go out as `Sat Feb 05 2022`.

In your example, if booking id:0 didn't exist, would someone be able to select `2022-02-10` as their checkout date or would it be included in the bookedDate dates and struck out?



Comment: If there was no booking 0, then the 10th would be struck out because the night of the 10th is booked. However, someone can select it as a checkout date because the night of the 9th isn't.

Comment: In theory, yes, and I need to work out how to get that theory into code. Currently, I'm getting a list of days that are "booked", and that list is being used to disable/strike out dates on the calendar. So if the 10th is struck out, it's also disabled. Even if it wasn't disabled, it would not be clear to the user, that they can select it as their check-out date.

Comment: The selection of check in/out dates is separate logic to the display of booked nights, the two should not be combined. If users are selecting nights, then the check in/out dates should be generated for them. If they are selecting check in/out dates, they should not be using the booked nights calendar for the reason you've mentioned. They should be able to select a checkout date that is after an available night, even if the night of that date is booked (per the example in the above comments).

Comment: Yes exactly, however, we use the same calendar for both, and as far as I know, that's how accommodation booking sites also do it (airbnb, booking dot com etc). Generally, calendars will show available check-in and check-out days. this is the most logical path for users to select when they will arrive and when they will leave. So I still need to find a way to check if a check-out day matches the next booking's check-in day, and if not, remove the check-out and check-in date from the list of "bookedDates", so it's not struck out on the calendar and available to select.

Comment: Airbnb uses a calendar that shows available checkin and checkout days, not booked nights. If there is a booking from the 1st to the 5th, it will strike out the 2nd to the 4th. The 1st can be selected for checkout but not checkin, the 5th for checkin but not checkout. [Try it](https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/8090201?adults=2&children=4&infants=1&federated_search_id=3e682dcf-9d27-42c8-b5e6-c5b48d0b77a7&source_impression_id=p3_1644234783_T60J0NGPjd4vuppQ&check_in=2022-02-21&guests=1&check_out=2022-02-28).

Comment: Yes, exactly, this is what I'm trying to achieve. The data coming in happens to be booked nights that's all. I just don't know how to get from that data to available check-in, check-out days. Apologies if there was some confusion in the wording.

Comment: So wherever there is one or more unbooked nights, don't strike out the first date of the next booking. That date can't be used for checkin, but can be used for check out.

Comment: yes, and it seems we're back at my original question, and the part I'm struggling with how to code. "How do you remove the last value in an array if it doesn't match the first value in the next array?" It could also be written the way you suggest... "How do you remove the first value in an array if it doesn't match the last value in the previous array". That's essentially what needs to be done right? If they match, then they are "booked nights". If they don't match, then there is an unbooked night. Thanks for going around with me on this one Rob, much appreciated! What do you think?